# How to jump the control to an option in a dropdown list by just pressing the first letter of it from the keyboard?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Following is the html code I am using to create a dynamic list of VF pages along with the Jquery function I am using to achieve the functionality.I found that using the keypress element would help me in achieving the requirement which I am looking for, but it does not work.

**HTML CODING**

```
<div id="VFPageListsDropDown">
    <span></span>
    <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdowns" data-dropdowns="#dropdowns-1" class="btn btn-primary dropdowns-toggle" id="btnSort" >
        <table width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td width="81%" id="BtnDropDown">Select VF Pages</td>
                <td width="19%"> <span class="caret"></span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </button>
    <span>
        <div id="dropdowns-1" class="dropdowns dropdowns-tip">
            <ul class="dropdowns-menu" id="VFPageListsDropDown"></ul>
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**Jquery function:**

```
 $('#').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {

var $this = $(this);
// attach key listener when dropdown is shown
$(document).keypress(function(e){

  // get the key that was pressed
  var key = String.fromCharCode(e.which);
  // look at all of the items to find a first char match
  $this.find("li").each(function(idx,item){
    $(item).removeClass("active"); // clear previous active item
    if ($(item).text().charAt(0).toLowerCase() == key) {
      // set the item to selected (active)
      $(item).addClass("active");
    }
  });

});
// unbind key event when dropdown is hidden
$('#').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
$(document).unbind("keypress");
})
```

Please suggest me if there is any solution for it...

Comment: .on should be used like this : on("event","selector",function(){}) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: _“How to jump the control to an option in a dropdown list by just pressing the first letter of it from the keyboard?”_ – what browser are you using that doesn’t have this functionality built-in already …? (Additionally, typing letters in rapid succession leads to jumping to the option that begins with those letters – your simple approach of only using the first letter will probably mess with that, and therefor you are _decreasing_ functionality …)

Comment: @CBroe- Yes I know that if I use the <select> and <option> tags I could achieve the the functionality which I want or even more than that.But the issue is that if I am using these two tags, only the background color comes to the option and not the control i.e if you type 'j' and there is a page called 'jaxb' ,it will jump to that page in the dropdown but when you click on it the page will not open